# Looping through table td to attach jQuery effect to each td

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table

I built a table like that:

```
<table id="testTable">

   <tr>
    <td dir="ltr"><a href="#">array()</a></td>
    <td>انشاء مصفوفة</td>
    <td>530</td>
    <td><a class="example1" href="#">12.5</a></td>
    <td>12.5</td> 
    </tr>

<thead>
        <tr> 
        <th colspan="5" rowspan="3" class="slide1" >
       <pre class="prettyprint lang-php ">

$a=array("a"=>"Dog","b"=>"Cat","c"=>"Horse");
echo $a["b"];
//الناتج 
Cat 

//مثال اخر
$a=array("Dog","Cat","Horse");
print_r($a);
//الناتج
Array ( [0] => Dog [1] => Cat [2] => Horse ) 

       </pre>
        </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>



     <tr>


                        <td dir="ltr"><a href="">array_push()</a></td>
                        <td>اضافة عنصر او أكثر لنهاية المصفوفة</td>
                        <td>530</td>
                        <td class="example2">12.5</td></td>
                        <td>12.5</td>

     </tr>

<thead>
        <tr> 
        <th colspan="5" rowspan="3" class="slide1" >
       <pre class="prettyprint lang-php ">

$a=array("a"=>"Dog","b"=>"Cat","c"=>"Horse");
echo $a["b"];
//الناتج 
Cat 

//مثال اخر
$a=array("Dog","Cat","Horse");
print_r($a);
//الناتج
Array ( [0] => Dog [1] => Cat [2] => Horse ) 

       </pre>
        </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>




   <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr"><a href="">array_rand()</a></td>
                        <td>استخراج مفتاح عشوائى من المصفوفة</td>
                        <td>530</td>
                        <td class="example3">12.5</td></td>
                        <td>12.5</td>
   </tr>

<thead>
        <tr> 
        <th colspan="5" rowspan="3" class="slide1" >
       <pre class="prettyprint lang-php ">

$a=array("a"=>"Dog","b"=>"Cat","c"=>"Horse");
echo $a["b"];
//الناتج 
Cat 

//مثال اخر
$a=array("Dog","Cat","Horse");
print_r($a);
//الناتج
Array ( [0] => Dog [1] => Cat [2] => Horse ) 

       </pre>
        </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>


........and multiple like that.....




</table>
```

and I want to make a for loop through it via js to slideToggle a `<thead>` of the same `<td>` that I clicked, and I tried something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i=1;i<=120;i++){
    $(".example" + i).click(function(){
      $(".slide" + i).slideToggle(500);
    })
  }
});
```

but nothing happened.

How to iterate this effect through each one, to slideToggle the specific thead that I clicked via the same td of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the hard way.

```
$('table a').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').slideToggle(500);
}}
```

The beauty of jQuery is that you can use RELATIVE selectors. `$(this)` will refer to the clicked element. `parents('tr')` will give you that element's parent `TR` tag. `next('tr')` will select the next `TR` tag. No need to deal with messy IDs at all. The goal is to have clean mark-up and let jQuery do the heavy lifting.

If you want to target a link with a specific class, use:

```
$('table a.example')
```

Comment: Not impressive - that's just the way to think when using jQuery.

Comment: yeah,maybe i am just newbie on using jquery